# how to find the files/(pwd of file) which is having a particular word below a particular word in directories and sub directories in linux

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

I have 200 folders, Each folder is having multiple shell and sql files, my requirement is to grep/find all the directories and the files which are having the below

Insert into dbname.table_name

Select

I want know what are all the files(pwd of the file) having insert into  ${dbname}.{table_name} followed by select which is in next line. Db name and table name is same for all

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but I've heard good things about **ripgrep** for searching the contents of a directory tree's worth of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grep -r -i -A1 "insert.into" | grep -i -B1 select`

`-r` will grep on all files in the current directory and recursively in all subdirectories.

`-A1` prints one line **A**fter the matching line,

`-B1` prints one line **B**efore the matching line.

So the first grep above will print all lines matching `insert.into` plus the next; the second grep will keep only those pairs that have a `select` on their second line.

(`-i` to ignore case)

You may then append `| grep -i insert.into | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u` to get only the file names.

Note this makes some assumptions:

- options `-A/-B` are only on Linux/gnu, not on plain Unixes like HPUX.
- if you have lines containing both `insert.into` and `select`, you'll get some funky output.